# How can I get Google contact list from swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to get contact list from swift 3? I've try with following URL to get contacts from Google but I've got `401. That's an error.`. Please help me how to solve it.

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?access_token=[TOKEN]&alt=json&callback=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(_YOUR_URL_) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(_YOUR_URL_, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Success") // Prints success
                })
            }
```

Comment: `_YOUR_URL_` is ?